# Convert MMM-YY to date where date before 1968

Tags: r

in my dataset, I have a date variable thats in MMM-YY format (e.g.Jun-68). I tried to convert them to yyyy-mm-dd format. But after using the following code, the dates that are before 1970 are changed to 20xx, instead of 19xx. Is there a way to fix it?

```
library(lubridate)
data$date2 <- dmy(paste("01-", data$date , sep =""))
```

example:
date     date2
Jun-68   2068-06-01 (but I want 1968 instead)

Comment: For your data, is there a clear cutoff year that delineates one century from the other? For example, does `Jan-25` always mean either 1925 or 2025?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @Rushabh's answer, here's an approach where you define the cutoff year for splitting the 2000's from the 1900's. In this case I've used 24 as the last year before sending dates back into last century:

```
date2 <- c("Jun-68", "Jan-99", "Jan-05", "Jan-24", "Jan-25")
x <- dmy(paste("01-", date2 , sep =""))
cutoff_yr = 24  # Everything past 2024 move back to 1900's
year(x) <-  (year(x) - cutoff_yr - 1) %% 100 + cutoff_yr + 1901
x
#[1] "1968-06-01" "1999-01-01" "2005-01-01" "2024-01-01" "1925-01-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
> x <- dmy(paste("01-", 'Jun-68' , sep =""))
> year(x) <-  1900 + year(x)  %% 100
> x
[1] "1968-06-01"
```

**Note**: But this is not safe option. As @Jon mentioned in the comment, you should have clean date years.

You can also use below function to define cutoff as @Jon Mentioned.

```
library(chron)
options(chron.year.expand = 
            function (y, cut.off = 24, century = c(1900, 2000), ...) {
                chron:::year.expand(y, cut.off = cut.off, century = century, ...)
            }
)


> as.Date(chron(format(as.Date("01-Jun-68", "%d-%b-%y"), "%m/%d/%y")))
[1] "1968-06-01"

> as.Date(chron(format(as.Date("01-Jun-18", "%d-%b-%y"), "%m/%d/%y")))
[1] "2018-06-01"
```